# How to stop threads from sleeping permanently at a debugger breakpoint?

Tags: ruby

I'm debugging a Ruby application which has a thread that provides a heartbeat to another process.

The heartbeat thread is very simple:

```
while @continue
  socket.write("OK\n")
  sleep 5
end
```

The problem I have is that when the debugger (byebug) hits a breakpoint in the main process, the heartbeat stops and essentially kills the wider application that I'm trying to debug.

I believe the problem is that when it enters sleep while at a breakpoint, it never wakes up until the debugger continues.

Is there anyway to prevent the debugger from globally preventing wake up from sleep like this?

Is there any concept of an `on_debugger_stop\start` callback(s) that I could leverage here to tell the remote process to expect the heartbeat to pause?

Comment: Do you get the same issue when using `pry`?

Comment: Actually no, Pry works fine in this respect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using MRI and your implementation looks (more or less) like this:

```
@continue = true
Thread.new do
  while @continue
    socket.write("OK\n")
    sleep 5
  end
end .join

# Debugging main thread
byebug  # e.g. Thread.list; Thread.list.last.terminate
```

You have 2 concurrent threads. Everything should work fine. However, there are some workarounds you can try (until byebug gets fixed):

1. Create a child process instead of a thread (using `fork`)

   ```
   @continue = true
   @child_pid = fork do
     while @continue
       socket.write("OK\n")
       sleep 5
     end
   end

   # Debugging main thread
   byebug  # e.g. [Process.pid, @child_pid]; Process.kill('SIGHUP', @child_pid)
   ```
2. Use `pry` instead of byebug

   ```
   @continue = true
   Thread.new do
     while @continue
       socket.write("OK\n")
       sleep 5
     end
   end .join

   # Debugging main thread
   binding.pry  # e.g. Thread.list; Thread.list.last.terminate
   ```

Also, make sure you check compatibility of your Ruby and byebug versions. Maybe a fix is included in current versions. I'm not aware of any debugger start or stop hooks.

I hope you find that helpful.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, both approaches work